# storage of different oracle data

Tags: sql, oracle, memory-management, transactions, plsql

my question is about Oracle data.In this scenario supposed there are two transactions running at about the same time in separate connections. These transactions have
identical code, but different data. The transaction calls the following package procedure:

```
PROCEDURE find(aKey Thing_tab.key%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO obj
    FROM Thing_tab t
    WHERE t.key = aKey;
END;
```

i want to know that what type of data would be stored in the following different parts of Oracle memory while and after these two transactions are running.

1. Shared SQL Area
2. Private SQL Area
3. Data Area
4. Stack Area

Comment: @Lukas Eder i am getting no response for my question which i really need.

Comment: Just wait. Your question was only viewed 10 times, so far. Some questions take longer, especially since your question requires some in-depth Oracle knowledge. I have added some more tags for you. Maybe that will attract some attention. Changing your user name might do as well...

Comment: @user758496 - what do you mean by "stack area"?  It's not an Oracle term.  Are you thinking of session memory?  In fact all of your terms are not Oracle standard, which is probably one of the reasons why you're not getting the immediate response you crave.  Anyway what's the emergency?

Comment: @APC PGA contains both Data Area and Stack Area (that holds local data lasts for the period of invocation of
a subprogram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terms are unfamiliar to me.  I will do my best to translate them into the normal Oracle terms, which I hope will answer your question.

#### Shared SQL Area

In Oracle the **Shared Pool of the SGA**.  In your scenario it will contain one parse tree for the SELECT statement and one execution plan.  There is just one because the Optimizer treats the PL/SQL parameter as a bind variable rather than a literal.

#### Private SQL Area

In Oracle the **Cursor**.  Each session will have its own area, containing one parsed version of the SELECT statement, and some other information used to process the statement such as the bind variable value.

#### Data Area

In Oracle the **Database Buffer Cache of the SGA**.  This will have one or more blocks of data from the table.  If this is a unique key record, the block(s) will be at the Most Recently Used end of the cache.  If the two selected records were physically close to each other, the second execution will have used the blocks already in the cache from the first execution.

#### Stack Area

Not sure what this equates to in Oracle.  Perhaps you mean **session memory in the Program Global Area**?   If so, it will contain the login info for each session.  Your PL/SQL doesn't use any session level variables; if it did, then they would be stored in session memory.

#### One thing you missed

The **Shared Pool of the SGA**.  This will hold one parsed and compiled form of the procedure which is executed by both sessions.

---

As you can see, Oracle has quite complicated memory structures.  This is because it strives to share as much as possible between users (sessions, processes).  What I have written here is a simplistic (and incomplete) precis.  The [Concepts Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm) devotes a whole chapter to memory architecture.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/memory.htm#i12483).

Comment: thanks for ur help...i am trying to understand whatever u have written above

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that anyone wanting to know more about Oracle internals and how it all relates to programming, pick up a copy of "Expert Oracle Database Architecture: Oracle Database 9i, 10g, and 11g Programming Techniques and Solutions" by Tom Kyte (ISBN 9781430229469).